# Can't get parser.ParseDir to parse Import statements

Tags: go

I'm having trouble getting parser.ParseDir to return any information in the returned struct.Imports field.  parser.ParseFile does seem to work however.  I would much rather use ParseDir than have to go through and call ParseFile on each file.  Here's what I've tried:

```
package crawlers

import (
  "fmt"
  "go/parser"
  "go/token"
  "os"
  "path/filepath"
)

type GoImports struct {
  //imports []*string
}

//returns fullpaths
func (g *GoImports) Crawl(entry string) ([]*string, error) {
  fp, err := filepath.Abs(entry)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  info, err := os.Stat(fp)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  if !info.IsDir() {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Entry point should be a path to a directory of a go package.")
  }
  fset := token.NewFileSet()
  //foo, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, fp, nil, parser.ImportsOnly)
  //foo, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, "/Users/dowen00/local/go/src/got/crawlers/testdata/barpackage", nil, parser.ImportsOnly)
  foo, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, "/Users/dowen00/local/go/src/opscli", func(os.FileInfo) bool { return true }, parser.ImportsOnly)
  //_, err = parser.ParseDir(fset, "/Users/dowen00/local/go/src/got/crawlers/testdata", nil, parser.ImportsOnly)
  //foo, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "/Users/dowen00/local/go/src/got/crawlers/testdata/barpackage/bar.go", nil, parser.ImportsOnly)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  //fmt.Printf("%c\n", foo)
  //fmt.Printf("%c\n", fset)
  for k, v := range foo {
    //for kv, vv := range v.Imports {
    //fmt.Printf("%s: %c\n", kv, vv)
    //}
    fmt.Printf("%s: %c\n", k, v.Imports)
  }
  return nil, nil
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never used the parser package, but one thing I noticed is that it looks like the docs indicate you can just set the filter to nil if you're not going to use it: https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/#ParseDir. That's just one less thing you have to worry about.

Comment: Follow up; this seems to work for me, both using a filter and without; if you do a print of k and v, you'll see a map was returned.

Comment: Yes, I see the map.  The map is empty however.  I am definitely importing stuff on every package I've tried this on, both built in packages and my own packages.  In every case the returned maps are empty.  When using ParseFile directly, the import maps are not empty.

Comment: Using your example, I also get no results. However, ranging over v.Files yields plenty of results. I'm unsure why there are no Imports, but that may be due to my understanding of the docs.

Comment: Nice find.  I was able to parse over the returned Files structure.  There is a File.Imports field which is not empty.  I guess I can use that.  Would be nice to know why this isn't working as presented though.

Comment: Sorry @Dale, hopefully someone else can chime in with more information!

Comment: That's how [ParseDir](https://golang.org/src/go/parser/interface.go?s=4420:4553#L129) is implemented, all it does is it aggregates the files and package names, `Scope` and `Imports` of the `ast.Package` type are left untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem.  If this, in fact, hasn't been implemented the go docs at https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/#ParseDir should probably be revised to avoid wasting people's time.

Here's the work around:

```
  for _, v := range foo {
    //for kv, vv := range v.Imports {
    //fmt.Printf("%s: %c\n", kv, vv)
    //}
    for kk, vv := range v.Files {
      for _, i := range vv.Imports {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", kk, i.Path.Value)
      }
    }
    //fmt.Printf("%s: %c\n", k, v.Files)
  }
```